# Adding an image to Pdf via Applet

Tags: java, applet, itext

I am trying to add an image to a pdf document via java applet. I am able to it successfully when i run the applet via applet viewer in eclipse IDE. But when i embedded this applet to a webpage, the pdf which is getting created is somehow corrupted. What am i doing wrong? I am using iText to do this.

Here is the code i use:

```
    Document document=new Document();

    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("C://Folder/abc.pdf"));
    document.open();

    Image img=Image.getInstance("C://New/abcd.png");
    img.scaleToFit(400,400);

    document.add(img);
    document.close();
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: There would be a serious security issue if you could run an applet that has access to the local C: drive of any visitor of your website without explicitly granted permission from that visitor. This is NOT an iText question. This is a java applet security question.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example). *"the pdf which is getting created is somehow corrupted."*  Somehow? Can you vague that up for us, it is in danger of containing useful information?  Screenshots (just upload them to any image share site and give the link) of how you expected it to look and how it actually looked might also help, if you cannot put it into words.

Comment: thank you for your comments. I found the solution. will post it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. the applet was throwing access control exception on line 
            Image img=Image.getInstance("C://New/abcd.png");

I signed the itext jar files, and got rid of the exception.